# How do I read mouse position in angularjs when a click is made?

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the in-element (x, y) position of a `ng-click`ed element. Using `clientX` and `clientY` gets transformed by the page scroll. Using `pageX` and `pageY` is not scroll-dependent, but it is absolute. Those four properties belong to the `$event` object, available inside the `ng-click` directive. How would I calculate the in-element x and y?

In jQuery I'd do something like:

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```

But now, I want to do it in angularjs (i.e. inside a `controller`, **not** inside a postLink function). What is a good way to do it? Is it safe to do the same but using `angular.element`? Or is there another way of calculating the values I need?

**Edit** Clarifying: In a controller, I'd try:

```
$scope.onClick = function($event) {
    //currently I can...
    var pageX = $event.pageX;
    var pageY = $event.pageY;
};
```

But I need to transform those coordinates to clicked-element related coordinates, since those elements are absolute. Consider an appropiate HTML:

```
<div ng-click="onClick($event)">Nestor Kirchner</div>
```

Comment: It's not too clear what you are calculating, can you provide examples?

Comment: Question is updated. also, I left sub-questions about your answer.

Comment: offsetX and offsetY will give you coordinates relative to the element being clicked. So if you click on the top-left corner of each list item, you should get 0,0. see updated plunk with styles added http://plnkr.co/edit/TnhEliSUgChCaMN4gmYn?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should get you started:

```
$scope.doClick = function(event){

    var x = event.x;
    var y = event.y;
    var offsetX = event.offsetX;
    var offsetY = event.offsetY;

    // you have lots of things to try here, not sure what you want to calculate
    console.log(event, x, y, offsetX, offsetY);
};
```

and HTML:

```
<div ng-click="doClick($event)"></div>
```

Please clarify what you are trying to calculate? Some examples?

Sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/TnhEliSUgChCaMN4gmYn?p=preview

Comment: Are `offsetX` and `offsetY` relative to the document? or should I accumulate `offsetX` and `offsetY` (respectively) for each ancestor?

Comment: Also: Are those properties cross-browser? Do I have to include jquery or are they included ootb?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli in this case, the offsetX and offsetY are the coordinates relative to the start of the <li> being repeated... so how far off the click is from the top left corner of each <li> element

Comment: Are those properties cross-browser AND supported by angularjs by default (i.e. without need to include jquery)?

Comment: these are built into angularjs, so they should be cross browser, try it out with different browsers just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in mozilla firefox.
For mozilla to work use,

```
var offsetX = event.originalEvent.layerX;
var offsetY = event.originalEvent.layerY;
```

---